# CSS not being rendered when moved to stylesheet

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, ejs

I have added a Bootstrap progress bar, which is overriding some of my CSS. I am trying to move the CSS to a stylesheet instead of being within my ejs file, but when I do, and loop it into the file through
`<link href="/views/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">` it refuses to do so, and I lose my styling.

Not that I think it mattes, but this is what is overriding my css

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-6pzBo3FDv/PJ8r2KRkGHifhEocL+1X2rV" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Here is my file structure

Views
|_Index.ejs, stylesheet.css, template.ejs

All of this is occurring in my index.ejs file, and not in my node backend (not included in file structure)

lastly, here is my progress bar:

```
<div id="loadingcontainer">
<div class="progress" style="height: 5px;">
    <div id="myprogress" class="progress-bar" style="color:#EB7051;" style="background-color: #ffffff" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%;" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the link tag to:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

And the HTML to:

```
<div id="loadingcontainer">
<div class="progress" style="height: 5px;">
    <div id="myprogress" class="progress-bar" style="background-color: red; width: 25%; color:#EB7051;" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#progress

Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/MWjNGxr?editors=1000

---

I would suggest you use the below one as you are using a very old version of bootstrap:

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

And HTML to:

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
```

Docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/progress/

Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/jOMgxRw?editors=1000

Answer (score 0):

If it's the bootstrap CSS that is overriding your styles, then this might help:
ensure that your "/views/stylesheet.css" appears after the "https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
link in your HTML document.

If that doesn't work, then the problem might be elsewhere.

One thing you could also try it to ensure that your custom CSS selectors are more specific than Bootstraps.
Eg:
if bootstraps is

```
.loader-class {
  color: red 
 }
```

yours should be:

```
.loader-class span { 
  color: red 
}
```

Comment: Yup, my stylesheet is being looped in after the bootstrap. Also tried to specify, and it does not work